# VBA Send email when cell equals cell in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to trigger an email when one cell equals another from a different sheet. I have done some reseach and found that Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1") seems the best way to do this but it's not working. If I keep it to the current sheet just using Range("C1") then no problem the email sends. But as soon I try and get another sheet involved it doesn't?

```
Dim xRg As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Range("D1:D10"))
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If (Range("D1") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")) Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code seems to work, what specifically isn't working for you? Can you specify and include the error that occurs.

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next` then re-run the code that doesn't work, and let us know the error you get, and what line is giving you the error.  Also I'm not sure what you mean with "Getting another sheet involved"  is that the addition of `Worksheets("Sheet2")` ?

Answer (score 0):

The Worksheet_Change event is linked to 1 sheet. If you put the following code in a worksheet code tab, it only works for that specific sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then
MsgBox ("Change happend!")
End If

End Sub
```

So, I think if you want this to happen for all your sheets, you can either call a module or copy it to all sheets.

Comment: Actually you are able to reference other sheets from the Worksheet_Change event, instead of your MsgBox, you could reference a different worksheet and add the value from Target to it (as an example), but you could also use the Workbook_SheetChange event, which applies to the whole workbook instead of a single worksheet...?